# I get a build error in axios when I run yarn build

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios, next.js

development enviroment
next.js
typescript

I get an error when I continue yarn build.
I get the　following error.

```
Property 'create' does not exist on type 'typeof import("/Users/match/node_modules/axios/index")'.
    20 | }
    21 | 
  > 22 | export const Axios = axios.create({
       |                            ^
    23 |   baseURL: baseURL,
    24 |   headers: {
    25 |     Accept: 'application/json',


> Build error occurred
Error: > Build failed because of webpack errors
    at build (/Users/match/node_modules/next/dist/build/index.js:13:917)
```

Comment: Check your `axios` import, are you using `import` or `require`. If it's require: `axios = require("axios").default`, or import: `import axios from 'axios';`

Comment: import * as axios from 'axios';

Comment: I'm using import * as axios from'axios';

Comment: Change to import axios from “axios” and build again

Comment: Axios.interceptors.response.use(
  (response: axios.AxiosResponse) => {
    return Promise.resolve(response.data);
  },
  (error) => errorHandler(error),
);

Comment: An error occurred at the location of axios.AxiosResponse

Comment: The namespace'axios' cannot be found. ts (2503)